# BufferedWriter: Write to file before it is closed

Tags: java, file, java-io, bufferedwriter

So in my program I have a `BufferedWriter` that is used to create log files of what the program is doing.

```
private BufferedWriter logWriter;
logWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile));
```

In several classes at several different times I call the below method to continue adding to the log file:

```
public void log(String logTXT)
{
    try
    {
        logWriter.write(logTXT + "\n");
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This all works fine, but the one thing that it does, is it doesn't actually write to the file until I call `logWriter.close();`.

What I'd like to see is the String being added to the file immediately after it called the method. Is there anyway that I can go around this, or am I just going to have to live with this, considering it isn't that big of a problem.

Comment: Have you tried reading the javadocs?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush() perhaps?

Comment: @Ryan : I can see that you got your answer but in case if you want to clear why it happens I have tried to explain it to you.
Please check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to explain your query with detail description and how you can resolve your issue.

First of all `BufferWriter` starts storing all the data its own buffer(which is based of allocation of memory) and once buffer is full it starts writing in it and then again go back to getting that buffer full.

This is really important because IO operation is too much costly and hence in order to make it efficient this buffer technique came into the picture.

However if you want to write down in file irrespective of buffer is full or not there is a method `flush()` that you can use that will resolve your issue.

Now let's consider your case : When you call `close()` method, it internally calls `flush()` method and then proceed further for closing that buffer. That's why you can see changes when you close it.

All in all just call `logWriter.flush();` after write everything and you are done (if you want BufferedReader to write down at particular time).

by using all this you can create your own custom method which can write instantly.

```
public void writeInstantText(BufferedWriter logWriter, String logTXT ){
  try
    {
        logWriter.write(logTXT + "\n");
        logWriter.flush();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

or just add `logWriter.flush()` after `write()` method.

Comment: I derived as much from the other comments and answers, but I appreciate the thorough answer, thank you.

Comment: Thats great. you are good enough that you can understand but I wrote this answer for all other people we will read it if future...
because they wont read all comments. and answer. they will simply follow the accepted answer or highly voted answer. as I do. :)

Answer (score 2):

The BufferedWriter has a buffer, so it will not write to disk before the buffer fulled(unless you called the flush or close method)

You can use PrintWriter.

Comment: `PrintWriter` would also require a `flush()` or a `close()`

Comment: PrintWriter has a construction method `PrintWriter(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush)`